# Что за кнопочка?

Tags: visual-studio

Всем привет, заметил при запуске проекта (из Visual Studio), появляется какая-то не понятная кнопочка... как найти справку именно по ней, я не знаю, нажимаю - вроде ничего не происходит.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, эта кнопка в отладочной панели переключает отображения чисел из десятичного представления в шестнадцатеричное.